# ./file versus file

Tags: linux, ctags

I'm reading a tutorial on how to set up Exuberant Ctags for a multi-level directory structure, and I saw the following line,

> Configure your editor to read the local tag file first, then consult
>   the global tag file when not found in the local tag file. In Vim, this
>   is done as follows: :set tags=./tags,tags,~/project/tags

Question is: (and this is probably more general than just Ctags) Why are ./tags and tags both specified as places to look? Don't they evaluate to the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

No. From `:help 'tags'`:

> When a file name starts with "./", the '.' is replaced with the path
>       of the current file.  But only when the 'd' flag is not included in
>       'cpoptions'.

So `./tags` searchs for the file, not in the current directory, but in the directory where the current file is located.

However, `tags` does search for the file in the current directory.

Yes, I'd also expect it to work the other way around...